# how to create complicated tablelayout on android

Tags: android, tablelayout

this is basically what i want to achieve : http://i52.tinypic.com/15qelwy.jpg

so far this is my main.xml file

```
<TableLayout
  android:paddingTop="80sp"
  android:paddingLeft="40sp"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  <TableRow>
   <TextView
    android:text="@string/questions"
    android:textColor="#000" 
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="18dip"
    android:layout_height="100px"
    android:layout_width="100px"/>   
    <ImageButton
     android:id="@+id/button_one"
     android:src="@drawable/button_flat"
     android:layout_width="227px"
     android:background="@null"
     />
    <ImageButton
     android:id="@+id/button_one"
     android:src="@drawable/button_flat"
     android:layout_width="227px"
     android:background="@null"
     />
  </TableRow>
 </TableLayout>
```

The result isn't pretty as it displays the 2nd button into another column.  How can i create just two columns; the first one is expandable and the next column contains multiple image buttons?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:paddingTop="80sp"
android:paddingLeft="40sp"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TableRow>
  <TextView
    android:text="@string/questions"
    android:textColor="#000" 
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="18dip"
    android:layout_height="100px"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" >   
        <ImageButton
         android:id="@+id/button_one"
         android:src="@drawable/button_flat"
         android:layout_width="227px"
         android:background="@null"
         />
        <ImageButton
         android:id="@+id/button_one"
         android:src="@drawable/button_flat"
         android:layout_width="227px"
         android:background="@null"
         />
 </LinearLayout>
 </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```